# Reusing ng2 components in different Nativescript Layout positions

Tags: typescript, angular, grid-layout, nativescript

I am writing an app in NativeScript using Angular 2.

Is it possible to define the position of your ng2 components in a parent Layout?

e.g. In my `test.component.ts`, the html layout file reads `<Label text="-" row="6" col="2" colSpan="2"></Label>`. I then just call `<test-comp></test-comp>` - this works great and creates the view I want but obviously, I want the component to be reusable.

So I would ideally like to be able to remove the row and col info from the component and then include the test component in a parent component like `<test-comp  row="6" col="2"></test-comp>`, I have tried that and is doesn't work, it just renders the component over the top of my gridLayout. Is there a way to achieve something equivalent?

## Update:

So here is a solution I have tried ...

#### test.component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "test",
    templateUrl: `Components/Test/test.html`,
    providers: []
})

export class Test{
    @Input() labelRow: number;
    @Input() labelCol: number;
    @Input() labelColSpan: number;
    @Input() labelRowspan: number;
}
```

#### test.html:

```
<Image src="res://test" stretch="aspectFit" [row]="lableRow" [col]="labelCol" [colSpan]="labelColSpan" [rowSpan]="labelRowSpan6"></Image>
```

#### parent.html:

```
<GridLayout columns="*, *, *, *" rows="15*, 5*, 20*, 5*, 5*, 5*, 5*, 20*, 20*" width="100%" height="100%" style.backgroundColor="white">
    <test [labelRow]="2" [labelCol]="0" [labelRowSpan]="6" [labelColSpan]="2"></test>
</GridLayout>
```

However, the test component does display, but it is in the top left-hand corner of the layout, not the specified location...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered your question in the [issue in github](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/278).
Your approach is correct - there is just a typo in the template (`lable` instead of `label`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you should do this. I've verified this works:

```
import {Component, Input, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
// UI
import {Image}                  from "ui/Image";
import {GridLayout}             from "ui/layouts/grid-layout";

@Component({
    selector: "test",
    templateUrl: `Components/Test/test.html`,
    providers: []
})

export class Test implements AfterViewInit{
    @Input() labelRow: number;
    @Input() labelCol: number;
    @Input() labelColSpan: number;
    @Input() labelRowspan: number;

    @ViewChild("element") element: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit(){
       const element = <Image>this.container.nativeElement;

       // GridLayout contains static methods for assigning grid location properties
       GridLayout.setRow(element, this.labelRow);
       GridLayout.setColumn(element, this.labelCol);
       GridLayout.setRowSpan(element, this.labelRowspan);
       GridLayout.setColSpan(element, this.labelColSpan);
    }

}
```

Your test HTML file should then look like this:

```
<Image src="res://test" stretch="aspectFit" #element"></Image>
```

#element is what saves the element into a variable which @ViewChild in the component can search for. Then we can use the AfterViewInit hook to assign these grid positions to the element using static methods found on GridLayout.

Note some ui components seem finicky... I've been doing this with StackLayout whereas ListView has come back null for me. The child component may need to be encapsulated with containers.

Here's another snippet in action: http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/snippets/2016/06/20/child-components-gridlayout.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know NativeScript and I'm not sure what the problem actually is that you try to solve. This might be what you want. You can just create inputs on your custom component and forward the values to the embedded component (can also be done in the other direction for `(event)` bindings):

```ts
@Component{(
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: '<Label text="-" [row]="lableRow" [col]="labelCol" [colSpan]="labelColSpan"></Label>'
  ...
})
class TestComponent {
  @Input() labelRow:num;
  @Input() labelCol:num;
  @Input() labelColspan:num;
}
```

Comment: Please see the update on my question, my interpretation of your solution is not working, please let me know if I have misunderstood you